# Need to get fields from lookup file with calculated values using spark dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a products file as below and the formula for cost price and discount in the lookup file. we need get the discount and cost price fields from lookup file.

product_id,product_name,marked_price,selling_price,profit

101,AAAA,5500,5400,500

102,ABCS,7000,6500,1000

103,GHMA,6500,5600,700

104,PSNLA,8450,8000,800

105,GNBC,1250,1200,600

lookup file:

key,value
cost_price,(selling_price+profit)
discount,(marked_price-selling_price)

Final output:

product_id,product_name,marked_price,selling_price,profit,cost_price,discount
101,AAAA,5500,5400,500,5900,100
102,ABCS,7000,6500,1000,7500,500
103,GHMA,6500,5600,700,6300,900
104,PSNLA,8450,8000,800,8800,450
105,GNBC,1250,1200,600,1800,50

Comment: so whats exactely in the lokkup-file? Values or just rules how to calculate `cost_price` and `discount` as expressions?

Comment: its just the rules how to calculate cost price and discount in the lookup file. values are present in the input file, the requirement is every time we need to lookup for formula of cost_price and discount and populate the values.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should make a `Map` out of your lookup-file, then you can add the columns using `expr`:

```
val lookup = Map(
  "cost_price" -> "selling_price+profit",
  "discount" -> "(marked_price-selling_price)"
)

val df = Seq(
  (101, "AAAA", 5500, 5400, 500),
  (102, "ABCS", 7000, 6500, 1000)
)
  .toDF("product_id", "product_name", "marked_price", "selling_price", "profit")


df
  .withColumn("cost_price",expr(lookup("cost_price")))
  .withColumn("discount",expr(lookup("discount")))
  .show()
```

gives :

```
+----------+------------+------------+-------------+------+----------+--------+
|product_id|product_name|marked_price|selling_price|profit|cost_price|discount|
+----------+------------+------------+-------------+------+----------+--------+
|       101|        AAAA|        5500|         5400|   500|      5900|     100|
|       102|        ABCS|        7000|         6500|  1000|      7500|     500|
+----------+------------+------------+-------------+------+----------+--------+
```

you can also iterate your lookup :

```
val finalDF = lookup.foldLeft(df){case (df,(k,v)) => df.withColumn(k,expr(v))}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import spark.implicits._
val dataheader = Seq("product_id", "product_name", "marked_price", "selling_price", "profit")
val data = Seq(
  (101, "AAAA", 5500, 5400, 500),
  (102, "ABCS", 7000, 6500, 1000),
  (103, "GHMA", 6500, 5600, 700),
  (104, "PSNLA", 8450, 8000, 800),
  (105, "GNBC", 1250, 1200, 600))
  
val dataDF = data.toDF(dataheader: _*)
val lookupMap = Seq(
  ("cost_price", "(selling_price+profit)"),
  ("discount", "(marked_price-selling_price)")) //You can read your data from look up file and construct a dataframe
.toDF("key", "value").select("key", "value").as[(String, String)].collect.toMap

lookupMap.foldLeft(dataDF)((df, look) => {
  df.withColumn(look._1, expr(look._2))
}).show()
```